# How to validate current section in JQuery fullpage plug-in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, fullpage.js

I'm using JQuery fullpage.js [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)
for a poll form that have several levels.
How can I validate (by regex) current section/level before this go to the next section by mouse wheel up/down and if the validation conditions is not correct, prevent this to going next section and show some alert?

I used this code but it doesn't work correctly:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#rollover').fullpage({
        anchors: ['l1', 'l2', 'l3','l4'],
        menu: '#lev_num',
        scrollOverflow: true,
        onLeave: function (index) {
            $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(index);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean with "can I validate by regex the current section". You have to specify how you want to do it if you want people to help you...

Comment: Regex validation isn't my problem, my problem is event handling.

Comment: you didn't help much width that answer... we need to know what do you need to validate a section... we don't know what you want to get or in general, what is your problem. I'd recommend to put some effort in your question if you expect any answer.

Comment: How are you planning to validate your form, in which action.

Comment: You could delete the `.fp-section` class of your section below so that the plugin thinks your form in is the latest section. You can do it using the `afterRender` callback. Then, in whichever action you use to validate your form, if it is correct, then you add the `fp-section` class again to the next section.  If you want to do the validation by mousewheel you will have to create your own mousewheel handler...

Comment: I'll add it as an answer so you can accept it for future visitors who arrive to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could delete the `.fp-section` class of your section below so that the plugin thinks your form in is the latest section. You can do it using the `afterRender` callback. Then, in whichever action you use to validate your form, if it is correct, then you add the `fp-section` class again to the next section. If you want to do the validation by mousewheel you will have to create your own mousewheel handler...